# circe automatic derivation - struggling with the imports

Tags: scala, circe

I have a method exposed on my API that looks like this:

```scala
def read[T](implicit decoder: Decoder[T]): T
```

A user can bring along any `T` they like and my code will attempt to parse the json result into a `T`.

The issue I want to resolve is that any user must also import `io.circe.generic.auto._` in order to get this to work and auto-derive the `Decoder[T]`.

Is there any way I can change my API to avoid the user having to bring this import?

Comment: Your description isn't quite correct. The user cannot bring any `T`, they can only bring a `T` for which there is an implicit value of type `Decoder[T]`. It is important that the user is aware that this depends on the `circe` library, not your code, so it is good that they are required to have that `import`.

Comment: Agree with @Tim, but would also like to note, that using `io.circe.generic.auto` may have cause weird side-effects: it generates Decoder[T] every time you try to resolve the implicit in a new scope, so you may end with a separate decoder instance for each method requiring `implicit decoder: Decoder[T]`

Answer (score 0):

It could be if you do it in a library - implicits would easily conflict causing troubles for your users.

In Typelevel Scala 4 can use [customizable imports](https://github.com/typelevel/scala/blob/typelevel-readme/notes/2.12.1.md#configurable-default-imports-pull5350-andyscott) - it didn't landed in Scala 2.12 but (after several iterations) [landed on 2.13](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/6764). You could recommend your users have some implicits always in scope this way once 2.13.0 is released, but that will be conscious decision on their part.

Comment: Hmm - your code doesn't appear to work (it doesn't compile). I did try exploring your idea of using a type alias, but I didn't come to anything. Yes this is for a common module/library shared between the application.

Comment: I guess you put type alias directly in the file, which Scala doesn't allow. Put it into package object and try to compile again.

Comment: Type alias was in a package object, the code you posted doesn't compile (nothing to do with the type alias, its the implicit that is defined)

Comment: I could have sworn it worked and I used it in my code, but apparently I was wrong. I edited the answer.